# How do I merge two armature ends into one?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I want to merge the armature joint to the other bone joint located at the 3D cursor.

I will also move the first joint onto the 3D cursor but how can I merge the two into one single joint at the 3D cursor?

I am using a metarig and learning all of this for the first time and I can see a dotted line between the two joints and I do not know what that technically means. But thought I'd mention it in case that is something that can help with the answer to this problem.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Are both bones you want to connect together part of the same armature? If they are part of the same armature you first select the bone with the tail you want to connect (left bone in your pic) then `Shift+Click` the bone with the head you want to connect (right bone in your pic) then press `Ctrl+P` *> Connected*

Comment: Oh 2 armature ends you said in your post. So you don't want to join the armatures with `Ctrl+J`? They have to be separate armatures?

Answer (score 1):

**Snap bone to cursor:**
[image]

- Select both armatures > Editmode > Select bone tail
- Armature > Snap > Selection to Cursor

**Snap bone with active tool to targets:**
[image]

- Select both armatures > Editmode
- Drag: Active Tool > PivotPoint: Active Element > Enable Snap > SnapTo: Vertex
- Select bone tail and pull to target